# target div inside div using .eq()

Tags: jquery, html

Pretty new to jquery but i was hoping to be able to target a div inside of a div.

I'm currently using this:

```
var items = $('#menu li').click(function() {

    var index = items.index(this);
    $(window).scrollTo(('#holder').eq(index), 800); 
});
```

and holder looks something like this

```
<div id="holder">

<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item test"></div>
```

but for some reason id doesn't seem to target a any of the divs. Or at least the scrolling isnt working on them. Could someone please advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple errors in your code. As ShankarSangoli stated you need to add a `$` to `('#holder')` to make it a jQuery object: `$('#holder')`.

Also `$('#holder').eq(index)` is selecting the `#holder` element of the current index, but you want to select the child of the `#holder` element instead. Try this: `$('#holder').children().eq(index)`.

Here is a working version of your code. Notice I used the `.animate()` function (called on the `html`/`body` elements since those are the ones that actually scroll, which depends on the browser being used):

```
var items = $('#menu').children().click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : $('#holder').children().eq($(this).index()).offset().top }, 800);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fCnM5/

Also notice that to get the index of the clicked menu item you can just use `$(this).index()` since the `.index()` function will get the index of the current selection based on it's siblings.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `$` while selecting `#holder` in your code, it is probably giving a syntax error. Try this.

```
var items = $('#menu li').click(function() {

    var index = items.index(this);
    $(window).scrollTo($('#holder').eq(index), 800); 

    //You can also use $(this).index()
    $(window).scrollTo($('#holder').eq($(this).index()), 800); 
});
```

Comment: No joy :(, but for got to add when I do this. It works `$(window).scrollTo( '.test', 800);` I'm just trying to make it dynamic

Comment: See my comment on Ori's answer. I believe you need to bind to either the `body` or `html` element for scrolling rather than the `window` element. Here's a jsfiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/fCnM5/2/

Answer (score 1):

`$('#holder')` refers to one element. `$('#holder > div')` refers to all the children of `#holder`, so you're probably wanting to do this:

```
var items = $('#menu li').click(function() {

var index = items.index(this);
    $(window).scrollTo($('#holder > div').eq(index), 800);   
});
```

You can also use `$('#holder > .item')`, `$('#holder').children()`, `$('#holder').children('.item')`.

Comment: I get the following error when using the `window` object to animate the scroll: `Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollTo'`: http://jsfiddle.net/fCnM5/1/

Comment: Are you using any specific scrollTo jquery plugin?